# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Tags: php, ajax

Столкнулся с проблемой и неделю пытаюсь с ней наконец разобраться.
На моём сайте присутствует система голосования, состоящая из 3 файлов:

poll.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getVote(int)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="poll">
<h3>Вопросы?</h3>
<form>
Да
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br>
Нет
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

poll_vote.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['voted'])){
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

$yespercentage = 100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2);
$nopercentage = 100*round($no/($no+$yes),2);

    echo "<style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
            td {
                font-size: .4em !important; 
            }    
        }
    </style>
    <h2>Результаты:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Да:</td>
<td>
<img src=\"poll.gif\"
width='$yespercentage'
height='20'>
$yespercentage%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Нет:</td>
<td>
<img src=\"poll.gif\"
width='$nopercentage'
height='20'>
$nopercentage%
</td>
</tr>
</table>";
die("Вы уже проголосовали.");
}

$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0){
    $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1){
    $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
$write = fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);

if($write !== false){
    $_SESSION['voted'] = true;
}
?>
<style>
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
            table * {
                font-size: .4em !important;
            }    
        }
    </style>
<h2>Результаты:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Да:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Нет:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

и poll_result.txt, который выглядит примерно так:

```
15||5
```

Иногда, пытаясь голосовать, ничего не происходит и в консоли отображается ошибка:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

Через некоторое время, зайдя на сайт, я с удивлением обнаруживаю, что код исправно работает, причём никаких изменений в нём сделано не было.
Возможно, что проблема с хостом, но нет никаких сведений об ошибках.

Буду добр, если поможете!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: ошикба 500 - всегда ошибка на сервере.. как чинить см. выше.

Comment: "никаких сведений об ошибках." --- также написано в дубликате..... ошибки просто выключены на хосте...надо либо включить их, либо смотреть в логах